# Overload ++ operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to deal with operator overloading at the first time, and I wrote this code to overload ++ operator to increment class variables `i` and `x` by one..
It does the job but the compiler showed these warnings:

> Warning   1   warning C4620: no postfix form of 'operator ++' found for
>   type 'tclass', using prefix
>   form  c:\users\ahmed\desktop\cppq\cppq\cppq.cpp   25
>
> Warning   2   warning C4620: no postfix form of 'operator ++' found for
>   type 'tclass', using prefix
>   form  c:\users\ahmed\desktop\cppq\cppq\cppq.cpp   26

This is my code:

```
class tclass{
public:
    int i,x;
    tclass(int dd,int d){
        i=dd;
        x=d;
    }
    tclass operator++(){

        i++;
        x++;
        return *this;

    }
};

int main() {
    tclass rr(3,3);
    rr++;
    rr++;
    cout<<rr.x<<" "<<rr.i<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This syntax:

```
tclass operator++()
```

is for prefix `++` (which is actually normally written as `tclass &operator++()`). To distinguish the postfix increment, you add a not-used `int` argument:

```
tclass operator++(int)
```

**Also, note that the prefix increment better return `tclass &`** because the result may be used after: `(++rr).x`.

Again, note that the postfix increment looks like this:

```
tclass operator++(int)
{
    tclass temp = *this;
    ++*this;     // calls prefix operator ++
                 // or alternatively ::operator++(); it ++*this weirds you out!!
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: `++*this;` wierds me out.  I use `::operator++();`.  Which wierds others out.

Comment: `++*this;` shows error saying: `Error 1 error C2675: unary '++' : 'tclass' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator c:\users\ahmed\desktop\cppq\cppq\cppq.cpp 14
`

Comment: @Shahbaz: I am using MS VC++.

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ is one of the least standard-conforming compilers. (Specially version 6 which was written before C++ became standard). Personally, I would suggest coding in a **real** compiler. If you are stuck with it, you'd have to refer to msdn to understand its shortcomings and its workarounds. Either way, the way I wrote it is the standard.

Comment: @Shahbaz: MSVC is definitely a real compiler.  MSVC6 was replaced in 2002.  That's (roughly) the equivalent of [GCC 3.0.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.0/caveats.html).  More likely he did something wrong.  Unrelated: the return type of `operator++()` is _usually_ `tclass&`.

Answer (score 6):

There are *two* `++ operator`s.  You defined one and used the other.

```
tclass& operator++(); //prototype for    ++r;
tclass operator++(int); //prototype for  r++;
```

Answer (score 5):

There are separate overloads for postincrement and preincrement. The postincrement version's signature is `operator++(int)`, while the preincrement's signature is `operator++()`.

You have defined `operator++()`, so you've only defined preincrement. However, you use postincrement on an instance of your class, so the compiler tells you that it will use a call to the preincrement function because no postincrement is defined.