# How do i make my code Know if i am calling pre increment or post increment operator 

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overload ++ operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318318/overload-operator)

Say i have a class in which i overloads both the pre increment operator `++v` and 
also overloads the post increment operator `v++`. But When i write these overloading
function say `Complex operator++(const Complex & c )` . How would i declare and 
define these two operators simultaneously in my code ?

How would my code know which overloading to call (pre increment one or post increment one)?
As far as i can think this Will probably depends on the way i declare these pre and post increment operator Can Someone help me out on this . Thanks in Advance

Comment: See for example [this link](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/97-overloading-the-increment-and-decrement-operators/).

Comment: I have to say it was a rather jerky move by whoever downvoted this.  It's certainly a legitimate question, and the way it was asked was direct and to the point.  Just because it's an easier question or that it was a duplicate doesn't say anything on the quality of the question.  You just point to the duplicate with it's answers and move on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.14:

```
 class Number {
 public:
   Number& operator++ ();    // prefix ++
   Number  operator++ (int); // postfix ++
 };
```