# C++ How do we differentiate postfix and prefix operator-overloaded functions?

Tags: c++, prefix

How do we explicitly implement a postfix unary operator overloading function?

eg. 'obj++'  Vs '++obj' ?

Both are unary operators, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318318/overload-operator

Comment: googlepedia says http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/97-overloading-the-increment-and-decrement-operators/